# Been trying for two hours on this thing, iterationg, slicing and joining a list of strings. The code looks perfect but it's giving a weird output

Tags: python, list, iteration

#my code

```
def sec_soc_nam(friends):
  for x in friends:
    return "".join(x[0])

print(sec_soc_nam(["tina","andre",'suzie']))
```

#output: t

#someone else's solution

```
def society_name(friends):
    return ''.join(sorted(i[0] for i in friends))
```

#ouputs the desired result: "ast"

Note: ignore the sorting
It's the iteration that's not working...only the first item is being outputted. I checked but there were no components missing.

Comment: What is the purpose of the function?

Comment: to make a string made up of the first letters of the names in the list

Comment: In your code you have the return inside the for loop. This stops the loop at its first iteration.

Comment: Have you noticed that you are returning from inside a loop? What is the difference if you return later, after finishing the loop ?

Comment: wow...thanks...I would have spent another 2 hours and not notice that. Thanks alot...it was driving me crazy...

Answer (score 1):

If you write the code as such

```
for x in friends:
    return "".join(x[0])
```

You will output only the first char (x[0]) of the first string ("tina")

Because the return instruction basically say to your function to stop there and return the first iterating value

The return should be executed only when you have collected all your start chars

```
"".join(sorted(i[0] for i in friends))
```

That's exactly what the other function does.

- first exract the first char (x[0]) from all your strings
- after that sort your chars in alphabetical order (sorted)
- then return the concatenation of such strings (return "".join)

Answer (score 1):

In case you still want to use the join keyword

```
def sec_soc_nam(friends):
  a = []
  for x in friends:
    a.append(x[0])
  return "".join(sorted(a))

print(sec_soc_nam(["tina","andre",'suzie']))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def sec_soc_nam(friends):
  return " ".join(friends)

print(sec_soc_nam(["tina","andre",'suzie']))
```

You are returning the item for each loop, not joining the entire list.

x[0] return the first letter of the item

Simply print(" ".join(["tina","andre",'suzie'])) will join the list for you

Answer (score 0):

you have a return assignment inside your for loop, so your program exits the function after the first loop, you could try this :

```
def sec_soc_nam(friends):
   a=''
   for x in friends:
     a=a+x[0]
   return a
```

Comment: so I noticed that I can't use the return after the for line, I have to separate it just like you did and then return...hmmm....very helpful thanks